# refresh part of php page

Tags: php, sql, database, refresh, chatroom

I am new to coding with `php` and `SQL`
I know `html, css and js`

I want to code for a simple chatroom web page
I have written the `sign in` and `sign up` part and I have saved some user accounts information in my database

but my problem is `how to refresh only a part of web page` using only `php`.

I have a `div` in my page for showing messages that are saved in database
and I want its content to be updated when a new message is gone to the database
but I don't want the whole page to be refreshed.

Please Help me wiith this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh only part of a webpage you can use AJAX. It is based on JavaScript and lets you update certain parts of a webpage without reloading it.
Here you can learn more: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server language - and based in resquest/response, like everything in web.

It means that you can't send information to the client after the response.

So if you want to make your page dinamic, you have to send some javascript to the client browser.

Depending on what you want to reload, you will need json and jquery/ajax to get the information through GET or POST. The you change the content of the current page using this.

In this case, you can use another PHP page like 'getmessages.php':

```
function getMessage(){
 $.ajax({
    url: "getmessages.html",
      context: document.body
    }).done(function() {
      $("#messagesdiv").html("-- body of message --");
    });
}

while(true){
  getMessage();
  sleep(1000);
}

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

You can parse the json to get the information wich is better. And it verify the information every second.

There are many tutorials out there that can show how to do this.

You can find JQuery [here](https://jquery.com).